# R grep pattern in a column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where one column is pattern and another is string. I want to iterate over each row check if the rows's string contains row's pattern and update the Matches column with T/F status
I tried

```
df<- df%>%mutate(Matches=grepl(pattern,string))
```

and got the following error.

> argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I understand that in the above code `grepl` is trying to read all rows of pattern column instead of the current row.

Is there any function which does this job or do I need to use a for loop and manually iterate over each row?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expeced output.  If each row pattern should be matched with 'string' in the same row, then try  `df$Matches <- mapply(grepl, df$pattern, df$string)`

Comment: Or if you need to use `dplyr`, then `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Matches = grepl(pattern, string))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we need to compare the 'string' with 'pattern' in each row, then use `rowwise()` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(Matches = grepl(pattern, string))    
# A tibble: 3 × 3
#  pattern string Matches
#    <chr>  <chr>   <lgl>
#1      sl  sling    TRUE
#2      ab   dare   FALSE
#3      cd   care   FALSE
```

---

It can also be done with `mapply` from `base R`

```
df$Matches <- mapply(grepl, df$pattern, df$string)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(pattern = c("sl", "ab", "cd"),
       string = c("sling", "dare", "care"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of rowwise function

Comment: If you want to stay with pure-`dplyr`, you can get better speed without `rowwise()` using a hybrid of these approaches: `df %>% mutate(Matches = mapply(grepl, pattern, string))`.