# create data.table column in pipe with grepl

Tags: r, data.table, grepl

I am looking for a way to create a new `data.table` column within a piped sequence using `grepl` looking for any occurrence of a particular string.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941680/grepl-across-multiple-specified-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373724/r-grep-pattern-in-a-column?rq=1) for help, and there seems to be many questions around this topic but it doesn't seem to directly address my issue.

Also, I may be misunderstanding the `data.table` syntax and am referencing the [Reference semantics vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html). I have the code below with two approaches that could be piped/chained but don't seem to work. The last option where the `data.table` column is created explicitly seems to work but I am wondering if it can be chained/piped.

To my understanding, using `lapply` within a `data.table` will apply a function to the entire column (ie `sum`, `mean`, `na.approx` which I found out from another posted question) but will not work on a row-wise basis. Also, I can apply a function to each row in a given column using the `new_col := function(x)`. So I would have thought one of those to work.

I am (only somewhat) aware that the `grepl` is expecting a single value but a vector is being supplied and I am unsure of how to fix that.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
> library(data.table)
> 
> a = c("housefly",
+       "house fly",
+       "HOUSEFLY",
+       "HOUSE FLY")
> 
> dt = data.table(insect = c("housefly",
+                            "house fly",
+                            "HOUSEFLY",
+                            "HOUSE FLY",
+                            "dragonfly",
+                            "dragon fly"))
> 
> # does not work but I could put this in chain/pipe
> dt[, fly_check := sapply(.SD, grepl, paste(a, collapse = "|")), .SDcols = "insect"]
Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> dt
       insect fly_check
1:   housefly      TRUE
2:  house fly      TRUE
3:   HOUSEFLY      TRUE
4:  HOUSE FLY      TRUE
5:  dragonfly      TRUE
6: dragon fly      TRUE
> 
> # does not work but I could put this in chain/pipe
> dt[, fly_check := ifelse(grepl(insect, paste(a, collapse = "|")), TRUE, FALSE)]
Warning message:
In grepl(insect, paste(a, collapse = "|")) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> dt
       insect fly_check
1:   housefly      TRUE
2:  house fly      TRUE
3:   HOUSEFLY      TRUE
4:  HOUSE FLY      TRUE
5:  dragonfly      TRUE
6: dragon fly      TRUE
> 
> # works but can't be chained/piped
> dt$fly_check = sapply(dt$insect, grepl, pattern = paste(a, collapse = "|"))
> dt
       insect fly_check
1:   housefly      TRUE
2:  house fly      TRUE
3:   HOUSEFLY      TRUE
4:  HOUSE FLY      TRUE
5:  dragonfly     FALSE
6: dragon fly     FALSE
```

Comment: Sorry, should have made the desired outcome more clear. It is the last printed `dt` in the code output. I am looking for the fly_check column to return `TRUE` if the insect column contains the string "fly".

Comment: I believe you are looking for: `dt[, fly_check := (Vectorize(grepl)(paste0(a, collapse = "|"),.SD)), .SDcols = c("insect")]`

Comment: Sure am! That works. You post it I will mark it. Thank you for the quick response @chinsoon12...and now others.

Comment: @chinsoon12 if you post your comment as a solution i will mark it as correct as you were the first to respond...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just a simple application of `%in%` to the `a` values

```
dt[ , fly_check := insect %in% a]
```

Which seems simpler than the application of `grepl` to the collapsed `a` values as a pattern.

```
dt[ , fly_check := grepl( paste0(a, collapse="|") , insect)]

> dt
       insect fly_check
1:   housefly      TRUE
2:  house fly      TRUE
3:   HOUSEFLY      TRUE
4:  HOUSE FLY      TRUE
5:  dragonfly     FALSE
6: dragon fly     FALSE
```

I suppose you might still choose the `grepl` strategy if you gained generality with `ignore.case=TRUE` or needed facilities provided by the 'perl' or 'fixed' parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for this, although a much simpler solution is given by @chinsoon12 (in the comments) which is just to pass the column name directly:

Logic: In data.table if you call it using .SD parameter , it means subset of data, which also suggest the column is passed not as a vector but as data.table object ( Hence you have to use Vectorize or other operations), On the other hand if you pass it directly as column, grepl has no problem working on vector like structure (@Chinsoon12 solution).

You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508482/what-does-sd-stand-for-in-data-table-in-r), its a very enlightening link.

```
dt[, fly_check := (Vectorize(grepl)(paste0(a, collapse = "|"),.SD)), .SDcols = c("insect")]
```

which leads to :

```
#       insect fly_check
#1:   housefly      TRUE
#2:  house fly      TRUE
#3:   HOUSEFLY      TRUE
#4:  HOUSE FLY      TRUE
#5:  dragonfly     FALSE
#6: dragon fly     FALSE
```